# How to handle dynamically created datepickers?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am trying to create date pickers dynamically (where I do not know the exact number).

I was referring to this tutorial http://javapapers.com/android/android-datepicker/.

In my code I create date pickers in the following way :-

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    edit = new EditText(this);
    edit.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    edit.setHint("Tap to select "+input_desc[index]);
    edit.setFocusable(false);
    edit.setClickable(true);


    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
        }
    });
    allElement_date.add(edit);

    row.addView(edit);
    table.addView(row);
```

The above code gets called unknown number of times. Then I have the follwing code:-

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
}
```

However as you can see there is no way to distinguish between the different clicks on the editText to set them differently.

```
public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) 
{
}
```

Could someone please help me how to figure out which edit text has been clicked and set them independently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guys, need your help here.

Comment: You could pass the reference to your EditText in the constructor of SelectDateFragment and also pass this in the method populateSetDate: 

`DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment(edit);`

Or just keep a reference to the row index and fetch the EditText from the table when needed. 

Since I am not sure if this is what you are going for, i left it as a comment instead of an answer. Please feel free to ask for more details if this is the approach you are looking for.

Comment: @Zerga Yes I was looking for something like this. Please suggest which would be the best way from the alternatives that you mentioned. And could you please elaborate a bit more on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your `SelectDateFragment` class with the following constructor, keeping a reference to the `EditText` field:

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private EditText edit

    public SelectDateFragment(EditText edit) {
        this.edit = edit;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(edit, yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
}
```

And in the `populateSetDate` method:

```
public void populateSetDate(EditText edit, int year, int month, int day) 
{
    edit.setText( day + "." + month + "." + year);
}
```

So that when you create the `EditText` field and its `onClick` event, you can pass the field:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

edit = new EditText(this);
edit.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
edit.setHint("Tap to select "+input_desc[index]);
edit.setFocusable(false);
edit.setClickable(true);


edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment(edit);
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }
});
allElement_date.add(edit);

row.addView(edit);
table.addView(row);
```

Of course you could use some more elaborate form of date formatting when calling `setText()` instead of just building it together with "+" string concatenation. And maybe you don't want to pass values for year, month and date separately, but that's just cosmetics that are not part of your initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly init TableLayout and in this layout add tableRow ,TableRow  not added directlly .

Comment: Of course I initialized the table layout first. This is not the complete code.